# Is there a way to load a large table from sql to pandas without creating a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, plsql, sqlalchemy, loaddata

I am using a server which has 64GB installed ram. I have a large table on database which has 6.5 million rows and 7 columns.I want to read it from database to pandas using read_sql() or read_sql_query() method. I used sqlalchemy create_engine and set the connection successfully.

```
cstr = 'oracle://{user}:{password}@{sid}'.format(
    user=user,
    password=password,
    sid=sid
)

engine =  create_engine(
    cstr,
    convert_unicode=False,
    pool_recycle=10,
    pool_size=50,
    echo=True
)

query = 'Select * From Table'

result = engine.execute(query)

df = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)
```

Everything is fine until the `df = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)`line. When I run this line Jupyter Lab throws me the error **"the kernel appears to have died. it will restart automatically"**

I do not want to create several csv files iteratively. Because I do not want to alocate that much space for the csv files. Just want to read the whole data once. But I am not sure if it is possible or not?

Comment: The answer to your question is **not** boolean. It depends on the amount of RAM you have and the number (and size) of records in the table. Try to add `limit` to the query and see if it works for N records. Consider switching to dask - https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/

Comment: You can use `chunksize` parameter

Comment: `chunksize` does not work

Comment: *"https://www.kdnuggets.com/2021/03/pandas-big-data-better-options.html"* How large is "large"? The issue might be related to to size of table in GB rather than number of rows. Also [this article (link)](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2021/03/pandas-big-data-better-options.html) might offer you some insight.

Comment: @APC I am trying to switch to Dask but syntax seems a bit different. What I tried is      
`df = dd.read_sql_table(table='Table', uri='oracle://user:password@host/sid',index_col='CST_ID', schema='A')`. But this time I got `KeyError: 'CST_ID'`. Do you have any idea about this error?